# Inherit from Base class with named constructors problems

Tags: c++

```
class MeshGeneration{
  public:
        static MeshGeneration CreateUnstrMesh() {
          cout<<"Unstr called"<<endl;
          return MeshGeneration(0);}
        static MeshGeneration CreateStrMesh() {
          cout<<"Str called!"<<endl;
          return MeshGeneration(1);}
        virtual void CreateHybridMesh(){}
  protected:
        MeshGeneration(int mesh_type = -1){
          string mstring;
          if(mesh_type == 0)
            mstring = "unstructured";
          else if(mesh_type == 1)
            mstring = "structured";
          else;
          cout <<"mesh_type = "<<mstring<<endl;
        }
};
class DerivedMeshGeneration:public MeshGeneration{
  public:
    void CreateHybridMesh(){
      cout<<"mesh_type = hybrid"<<endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argcv[]){
  MeshGeneration m1 = MeshGeneration::CreateUnstrMesh();
  MeshGeneration m2 = MeshGeneration::CreateStrMesh();
  MeshGeneration m3 = DerivedMeshGeneration::CreateUnstrMesh();
  m3.CreateHybridMesh(); // not working as expected..
  return 0;
}
```

---

The last function is not working as expected--print out "mesh_type = hybrid". And I think
something is wrong when I inherit the base class. Any suggestions are appreciated!
it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two major problems:

In order to use a polymorphic base class like you're attempting, you must use a reference, pointer, or smart pointer.  Since the objects `m1`, `m2`, and `m3` are plain variables of type `MeshGeneration`, they will never really be a `DerivedMeshGeneration`, no matter what the function to the right of the `=` originally created.

`DerivedMeshGeneration::CreateUnstrMesh()` is the same function as `MeshGeneration::CreateUnstrMesh()`, so it never creates a derived object in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. I tried " DerivedMeshGeneration m3 = DerivedMeshGeneration::CreateUnstrMesh();", and when I compile, I got the error message like "error: conversion from ‘MeshGeneration’ to non-scalar type ‘DerivedMeshGeneration’ requested", any advice on that?

Comment: @user606769: The return type of `DerivedMeshGeneration::CreateUnstrMesh()` is still `MeshGeneration`, because it's the function from the base class. And you can't assign an object of the base class type to an object of the derived class type.

Comment: @Xeo,  I have trouble instantiate my existing derived class, suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Here your code prints:

```
Unstr called
mesh_type = unstructured
Str called!
mesh_type = structured
Unstr called
mesh_type = unstructured
```

and it is what it should happen.

`m1`, `m2` and `m3` are objects of type `MeshGeneration`, and `MeshGeneration::CreateHybridMesh` does not print anything.

In order to print `mesh_type = hybrid` you should have an object of type `DerivedMeshGeneration` (or a pointer/reference to a `DerivedMeshGeneration` or a `MeshGeneration` pointing/referencing to an instance of `DerivedMeshGeneration`).

Comment: Thanks. I tried "  DerivedMeshGeneration m3 = DerivedMeshGeneration::CreateUnstrMesh();", and when I compile, I got the error message like "error: conversion from ‘MeshGeneration’ to non-scalar type ‘DerivedMeshGeneration’ requested", any advice on that?

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
MeshGeneration m3 = DerivedMeshGeneration::CreateUnstrMesh();
```

You are making a copy of the return value of DerivedMeshGeneration::CreateUnstrMesh(), and that copy is of type MeshGeneration. Thus the function that gets called is the one in MeshGeneration.

You should be using pointers or references instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
DerivedMeshGeneration::CreateUnstrMesh()
```

doesn't create an instance of `DerivedMeshGeneration`, rather it creates an instance of  `MeshGeneration`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. Now this works as I expected:

DerivedMeshGeneration * m3 =  new DerivedMeshGeneration;

m3->CreateHybridMesh();